# Modular PCB design in Altium

Tags: pcb, altium

I need a way to reuse my PCBs that I designed before in my new board as a module. the problem with multichannel design is that I should change some component names in schematic, so I can not use the previous designed PCB with copy and paste (for example I have C2 in 2 modules)
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use device sheets for that. See the respective [wiki article](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Using+Device+Sheets). You have to play around with the naming conventions in the settings dialog, as not all combinations seem to work properly...

Convert your current schematic into a device sheet, then instantiate it multiple times.

Combine this with the pcb snippet feature to allow for rapid placement of pre-routed designs, e.g. power supply, op amp and so on.

The suggested manual act of copying, re-annotating, replacing, possibly re-routing is the poor man's equivalent, but much more time consuming. Depending on the design, initial setup and learning curve quickly amortize.